# Can I change a text file into a spreadsheet with grid lines, using a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have the information below and I want it to look like it is in a spreadsheet with a header.

```
cat TEXT-FILE.txt

SOMETHING5 : 11111111 : 1969-08-12 : 42.34
SOMETHING4 : 22222222 : 1969-08-12 : 700.12
SOMETHING3 : 333333333 : 1969-08-12 : 300.2
SOMETHING2 : 44444444444 : 1969-08-12 : 200.2
SOMETHING1 : 5555555555 : 1969-08-12 : 100.34
```

This is as far as I've gotten with my script

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./TEST-FILE.txt
do
        sed -i -e "s/:/|/g" $file
        sed -i '1iIdentify | Misc | Date | Amount | Confirmation ' $file
done
```

The output is now:

```
Identify | Misc | Date | Amount | Confirmation
SOMETHING5 | 11111111 | 1969-08-12 | 42.34
SOMETHING4 | 22222222 | 1969-08-12 | 700.12
SOMETHING3 | 333333333 | 1969-08-12 | 300.2
SOMETHING2 | 44444444444 | 1969-08-12 | 200.2
SOMETHING1 | 5555555555 | 1969-08-12 | 100.34
```

I'm unsure how to make the lines match up, also the Confirmation column is blank as this will eventually be manually entered info.

Long story Long - I wanted this output to look like a proper spreadsheet, including grid lines. No other questions I've found exactly answer what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm unsure how to make the lines match up

Have a look at `column`.

#### Original file

```
$ cat columns.txt 
Identify | Misc | Date | Amount | Confirmation
SOMETHING5 | 11111111 | 1969-08-12 | 42.34
SOMETHING4 | 22222222 | 1969-08-12 | 700.12
SOMETHING3 | 333333333 | 1969-08-12 | 300.2
SOMETHING2 | 44444444444 | 1969-08-12 | 200.2
SOMETHING1 | 5555555555 | 1969-08-12 | 100.34
```

#### With column

```
$ column -t columns.txt 
Identify    |  Misc         |  Date        |  Amount  |  Confirmation
SOMETHING5  |  11111111     |  1969-08-12  |  42.34
SOMETHING4  |  22222222     |  1969-08-12  |  700.12
SOMETHING3  |  333333333    |  1969-08-12  |  300.2
SOMETHING2  |  44444444444  |  1969-08-12  |  200.2
SOMETHING1  |  5555555555   |  1969-08-12  |  100.34
```

As you can see from above, using column makes the output align nicely, and the blank `Confirmation` column is indeed, umm, visibly blank!

Online man page **[here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/column)**.

---

> I wanted this output to look like a proper spreadsheet

If you want to make things even *more* spreadsheet-like, I would suggest you check out Python and the [`beautifultable` module](https://pypi.org/project/beautifultable/).

Using the above, you can (fairly easy) get output like:

```
+----------+------+--------+
|   name   | rank | gender |
+----------+------+--------+
|  Jacob   |  1   |  boy   |
+----------+------+--------+
| Isabella |  1   |  girl  |
+----------+------+--------+
|  Ethan   |  2   |  boy   |
+----------+------+--------+
|  Sophia  |  2   |  girl  |
+----------+------+--------+
| Michael  |  3   |  boy   |
+----------+------+--------+
```

Comment: I updated my script to include that line 
` column -t $file > temp-123.txt`

Comment: When I try to email this file as the body of the email, i lose the formatting from the column command. Do you know how to retain that formatting?

Comment: Try using a fixed width font in your e-mail client.

Comment: Is there a way to make column output the last `|` in every row, even when `Confirmation` is empty? I think that would look nicer.